# Algorithm for finding an argument contained within another argument

Tags: c

I'm trying to devise an algorithm that finds if a string argument is found within another string argument. (2 arguments)

So far I've got;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

const char * argument_1= argv[0];
const char * argument_2=argv[1];

if (argc != 3)
    {
    printf("I wanted 2 arguments!");
    }
else
    if (strstr (argument_2, argument_1)!=NULL)
        {
        printf ("true\n");
        }   
    else
        {
        printf("false\n");
        }

}
```

And everytime I run it, I recieve "false"

Why is this? :(

Comment: Why not simply `if (strstr (argument_2, argument_1) printf ("true\n");` presuming you want to know if *argument_1* is contained within *argument_2*. (reverse the arguments if it is the other way around)

Comment: I didnt know that existed! Seems like that does exactly what I'm looking for..

Comment: It along with `strpbrk` and the rest of the goodies in `string.h` can save a lot of reinventing the wheel. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Oh boy, can't wait to look into that!

Answer (score 1):

Element 0 in argv is the program name. You should compare number 1 and 2, not 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Should the line

```
 for (j=0; j<length_1;i++)
```

be

```
 for (j=0; j<length_1;j++)
```

as you have a typo

Comment: Thanks! I switched over to while loops to help clean some stuff up. Hopefully this works.